# How to generate a randomized list of a sequence of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want a function to generate a list of length n containing an arithmetic sequence of numbers between 0 and 1, but put in a random order.

For example, for the function

```
def randSequence(n):
    ...
    return myList
```

```
randSequence(10)
```

returns

```
[0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.7]
```

and

```
randSequence(5)
```

returns

```
[0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.6]
```

Currently, I have it so it generates the sequence of numbers in one loop, and randomizes it in another, as follows:

```
def randSequence(n):
    step = 1 / n
    setList = []
    myList = []
    for i in range(n):
        setList.append(i * step)
    for i in range(n):
        index = random.randint(0, len(setList) - 1)
        myList.append(setList.pop(index))
    return myList
```

Unfortunately, this solution is slow, especially for large numbers (like n > 1,000,000). Is there a better way to write this code, or even better, is there a function that can do this task for me?

Comment: Why not use the `shuffle` function?

Comment: For large `n`, you may be better off using `numpy.random`.

Comment: Try `numpy.random.random`

Comment: @AccLok that will not guarantee the arithmetic progression property.

Comment: @HeapOverflow shuffle is quite a bit faster! Thank you for that. Even still, I'm still curious if there is already some function that does this for you, as in generating the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out that the main reason for bad performance of your code is due to this line:

```
myList.append(setList.pop(index))
```

The time complexity `list.pop` from the middle of a list is roughly `O(n)` since popping from the middle of the list forces Python to move a bunch of memory around. This makes the net complexity `O(n^2)`. You can drastically improve performance by making changes inplace, e.g.:

```
def randSequenceInplace(n):
    'a.k.a. Fisher-Yates'
    step = 1 / n
    lst = [step * i for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n-1):
        index = random.randint(i, n - 1)
        lst[i], lst[index] = lst[index], lst[i]
        # myList.append(setList.pop(index))
    return lst
```

---

For completeness, you can go with a vectorized `numpy` solution or use the previosuly mentioned `random.shuffle` to get even better performance. Timings:

```
n = 10**6
%time randSequence(n)
# CPU times: user 1min 22s, sys: 33 ms, total: 1min 22s
# Wall time: 1min 22s
%time randSequenceInplace(n)
# CPU times: user 1.33 s, sys: 1.91 ms, total: 1.33 s
# Wall time: 1.33 s
%timeit np.random.permutation(n) / n
# 10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Maybe bad wording on my part. The idea was that moving `O(n)` bits of memory is intuitively worse than just iterating over `O(n)` bits in memory, hence the "in addition" part.

Answer (score 2):

@HeapOverflow suggested exchanging the second loop for the shuffle function:

```
def randSequence(n):
    step = 1 / n
    myList = []
    for i in range(n):
        myList.append(i * step)
    random.shuffle(myList)
    return myList
```

Which is an order of magnitude faster than before. From past experience, I suspect that the pop function on lists is rather slow and was the main bottleneck in the second loop.

Comment: "an order of magnitude" for what n? Since your original was quadratic and this one is linear, this depends on n.